# how to implement bitwise XOR in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

i would like to implement XOR operation of 1000000^10100001.

```
def keygen(key):
    print (key)
    k0 = key
    w0 = k0[0:8]
    w1 = k0[8:]

    w2 = int(w1) ^ int(10000000)
```

But im not getting the correct output. My `w1` is:`10100001` and my binary o.p `w2` is:`0b100110001011110110000010`.

I should get: `00100001`

Comment: If you want to use the number as a bitflag, make it binary with `0b100000`

Comment: i dont want bit flag, just need to implement XOR.. Any suggestion?

Comment: Suggestion: blindly follow my comment and see what happens.

Comment: @BallpointBen, It should be `0b10000000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `0b...` to denote binary number.

Also when converting string to a number using [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), specify base 2 (the second optional parameter). Otherwise it is interpreted as a decimal number:

```
w2 = int(w1, 2) ^ 0b10000000
#            ^    ^^------------ binary (= 128 in decimal)
#            |
#            optional argument (base 2)
```

And, you don't need to call `int` for `0b10000000`, because it's already an int object.

---

**UPDATE** If you want to get a string representation back, use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes#str.format) or [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) with format specify `08b` (0: leading zeros, 8: at least 8 digits, b: binary)

```
>>> format(w2, '08b')
00100001
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. One more question.. Is there a way to remove the bit flag?
or do ive to convert to string and remove the 0b

Comment: @GoldyTomy, binary `0b10000000` is decimal `128`. So, you can replace the line with `w2 = int(w1, 2) ^ 128`

Comment: my requirement is to use bits for my program, after the XOR operation i need to work with bits. Thats why i cant use 128.
Moreover, if i change the input w1 to 10011010, my output becomes 0b11010, which is not eight bit output.

Comment: @GoldyTomy, I don't get what you mean. Do you want result back as a string? then try `bin(w2)` (this will give you a string with a prefix `0b`), `format(w2, 'b')`, `format(w2, '08b')` (at least 8 string with leading 0 if needed) or `'{:08b}'.format(w2)`, ...

Comment: so, what im looking is w2 = 10011010 ^ 10000000 and the output should also be 8 bit output in bits.
the above format you gave is working but it just removes the 0 in front. Im working in a code which deals only with  bits, so i guess i need to check the output and then append the missing zeros if there are any.

Comment: @GoldyTomy, Did you try `format..`, `'..'.format(..)` I suggest in the previous comment? I also updated the answer to include it. Please try it first.

Comment: yes, it removed 0b. but the zeros are still missing.

Comment: @GoldyTomy, I gave you many options. One gave you with 0b prefix, other without the prefix,  another with leading 0. The one in the answer should be waht you want.

Comment: I apologize its working now. Thanks for the help.. :) it worked with format (w2, '08b').